# Force TextField with type number to display dot as decimal separator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, html-input

I am using `material-ui` to render a `TextField` component in my `react` app. It's somehow forcing all the `<TextField type="number />` to have decimal separator as comma (,) instead of dot (.) which is confusing for the targeted users.

Is there any way to force it to always show dot as the decimal separator, regardless of locale?

I have created a [small example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-hsj2l). just try to enter a number with decimals and click outside and it'll convert it into comma. This is probably because of my current device locale, but still I want to force a dot for everyone.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#floating-label)? Maybe will be helpful for your

Comment: @RicardoGonzalez I saw that, but they use type="text" which I use without those plugins too. I need the number type, so that user can enter numbers only and they can use that increment-decrement buttons too.

Comment: @noob A solution would be to use a third-party library, where do you stand on that decision?

Comment: @minus.273 I'd try to avoid it if possible, however, if that's the only solution, I can do that. The only thing is I want to keep the type as number, otherwise, I am getting the dot with text type anyway even without any library.

Answer (score 3):

For me, setting the language attribute to `"en-US"` in the `inputProps` worked:

```
<TextField
    type="number"
    inputProps={{step: "0.1", lang:"en-US"}}
 />
```

Comment: I just checked and unfortunately, it doesn't work. You can try with changing the locale to `fr-fr` (or any European locale) and see if it changes the decimal separator to a comma instead of dot for you.

Answer (score 0):

As per my suggestion of using a third-party library to be integrated in the Textfield component; You could use the [react-number-format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-number-format) library as an inputProp for the Textfield. It works because the number formatter offered by the aforementioned library has a `decimalSeparator` prop which defaults to the one character string `"."`

The custom number formatter would go like this:

```
import NumberFormat from 'react-number-format';

interface NumberFormatCustomProps {
  inputRef: (instance: NumberFormat | null) => void;
  onChange: (event: { target: { value: string } }) => void;
}

function NumberFormatCustom(props: NumberFormatCustomProps) {
  const { inputRef, onChange, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <NumberFormat
      {...other}
      getInputRef={inputRef}
      onValueChange={values => {
        onChange({
          target: {
            value: values.value
          }
        });
      }}
      isNumericString
    />
  );
}
```

And it could be used in a number Textfield like this:

```
<TextField
      label="react-number-format"
      value={values.numberformat}
      onChange={handleChange("numberformat")}
      id="formatted-numberformat-input"
      InputProps={{
        inputComponent: NumberFormatCustom as any
      }}
      type="number"
/>
```

For a fully functioning example, check out this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-iny12).

Comment: I can still see comma in the sandbox as decimal separator. Additionally, I can't input decimal values in the TextField, it gets reset when I press dot key. I had to paste a decimal value to check which didn't work either.

Comment: @noob You mean that if you type in a comma, the Textfield lets you input that?

Comment: Nope, I am trying to type a float value, such as 23.20, but as soon as I enter the dot after 23 it clears. I pasted the same value, but when I loose focus on the TextField it appears as 23,20.

Comment: That is an interesting reaction from the library... That means it does not happen in my locale? Will look more into it later :)

Comment: I can confirm that... my locale is French (fr-fr or whatever) and the demo behaves the same way as described by @noob.

Answer (score 0):

I came out with solution that accepts both , and . separators using regex validator.

In addition of controlling input label, I control external numeric state <number | null>.

In my solution user can only input decimals separated . or , The input label and numeric state only changes if user input is convertable to float, In case of empty "" input, numeric state is set to null.

```
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState<string>("")
    const [numericValue, setNumericValue] = useState<number | null>(null)

         return (<TextField
                    inputMode={"numeric"}
                    onChange={(e) => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        // if new value is valid float
                        if (/^([\d]*[,.]?[\d]{0,2})$/.test(e.target.value)) {
                            setInputValue(e.target.value);
                            const parsed = parseFloat(
                                e.target.value.replaceAll(",", ".")
                            );
                            setNumericValue(isNaN(parsed) ? null : parsed)
                        }
                    }}
                    value={inputValue}
                />);
```